# How to change a timespan into decimal format in excel?

Tags: excel

I have the following problem. In my excel sheet, I subtracted two time values to get its timespan.
Here is an example:

```
16:30-8:00=8:30
```

the cell format is a time so its all fine. **Now the problem:**
I need to show the timespan also as a decimal. So the `8:30` should be a `8,50`
Anybody know how to do this?

Comment: Use `format cells` option, go to `custom format`, on type use `hh.mm`

Comment: How is `50` derived? Dividing by 60?

Comment: its 30minutes as a decimal number

Comment: hh.mm is not working because it will still be 8.30 and not 8.50

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `=24*(B2-C2)`, where the cell where calculation happens should be formatted in 2 decimal number format .

B2= start time.

C2= End time.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

Say A3 is 08:30, you can put this in A4

`=HOUR(A3) & TEXT(MINUTE(A3)/60, ".00")`